# Is the Grails 3.3.2 dependency on tomcat-embed-logging-log4j-8.5.2.jar an issue due to recent log4j vulnerabilities?

Tags: tomcat, grails, log4j

I have 5 grails servers built on 3.3.2 and they all have this dependency:

```
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-rest: -> 3.3.2
|    +--- org.grails:grails-plugin-datasource:3.3.2
|    |    \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-log4j:8.5.2
```

Comment: This is kind of a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70647951/is-tomcat-embed-logging-log4j-impacted-by-recent-log4j-vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the Grails 3.3.2 dependency on tomcat-embed-logging-log4j-8.5.2.jar
> an issue due to recent log4j vulnerabilities?

No.  Your app could still have a dependency on something that brings the vulnerability in, but `tomcat-embed-logging-log4j-8.5.2.jar` does not.

Comment: Some additional information is available at https://grails.org/blog/2021-12-14-log4j2-cve.html.

Comment: If you add the `project-reports` Gradle plugin to your build (`apply plugin:"project-reports"`) and then run `./gradlew dependencyReport`, that should generate `build/reports/project/dependencies.txt` which will show you your transitive dependency graphs.